# how to create different layout for different device and orientation in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am a newbie in android app development, so forgive me if I replete the question. 
My question is about layout my app in different device and orientation effectively .
 I have a list of product that that I have to show in a activity with their respective metadata and images. I use custom listview for this it looks fine in portrait view but in landscape view it seems like waste of available space (specially tablet device it looks very bad)  .
 
So i want to know how to use extra available space to show more product in same row ? Should i use different layout for different orientation ? should i show one product in a row if device in portrait and two product in a row if it is in landscape view ? or there is something better than this (something that show product in a row according to available space 1,2,3 or more product in a row according to available space).

Comment: It sounds from your situation like you should use different layouts for the different situations. See this question to see how you do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations

Comment: thank for your comment . should i also need to change my listview to tabview (if i need to show two product in a row )

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. I use listview a lot but I've never tried tabview.

Answer (score 1):

basicall you will need to create different resources for each orientation and the android framework will do the rest.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16567362/2580623) answer, if you need any further explanation just tell me

Comment: thanks @Basil . So I have to use list and grid both views according to orientation.